# How to wrap innerHTML div with Class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I want to be able to copy the text from element id 'myModal' to 'purchaseNotice' and wrap 'purchaseNotice' with new class.

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('myModal');
var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('purchaseNotice').wrapInner( "<div class='new'></div>");
MyDiv2.innerHTML = MyDiv1.innerHTML;
```

The code above works until I add `.wrapInner( "<div class='new'></div>")` - how shall I wrap this?

Comment: Side note, if you're using jQuery, do this `$('#purchaseNotice')` not this `document.getElementById('purchaseNotice')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var MyDiv1 = document.getElementById('myModal');
var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('purchaseNotice')

if ($("#myModal").length) {
    $("#purchaseNotice").addClass("your-class").show();
    MyDiv2.innerHTML = MyDiv1.innerHTML;
} else {
    $("#purchaseNotice").hide();
}
```

This code works great! It copies a innerHTML of the id element 'myModal' to 'purchaseNotice', then it checks if 'myModal' exists within the DOM, if so it adds a new class, if not then hides it totally.
This works great when you have a textbox in which you don' want to show this information, i.e. product/service description can contain disclaimer and you want to make it appear at the top of the screen rather then in the description itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can do it like this : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/32tAx/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#purchaseNotice').html($('#myModal').html()).wrapInner("<div class='new'></div>");   
});
```

**Update**

Sorry, noticed you wanted to wrap the purchaseNotice in the new div. You would then use `wrap()` see here : http://jsfiddle.net/32tAx/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#purchaseNotice').html($('#myModal').html()).wrap("<div class='new'></div>");   
});
```